# PrimeFaces and visible autocomplete in SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, selectonemenu

Is there any way to achieve the following requirement:

1. Use JSF with PrimeFaces,
2. Use a `SelectOneMenu` with autocomplete,
3. Make the input text visible: i.e. not only typing (as it is already supported), but the user should also have an visible typing field to select a given menu item.

I guess it should be a combination of (customized) `filtering`, `editable` input and server-side validation, but I did not find out how.

Comment: Are you looking for the advanced example here? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml . Otherwise I dont understand the question

Comment: Thank you so far. It should be a combination of the `Editable` and `Advanded`case. Take the `Editable` field and enter `New`. Right then it does not autocomplete to _New York_, but it submits the _New_ input only. The `Advanced` example fits the behaviour, but the input field shows up BELOW the initial selection field - this should not happen. Oh, and it should avoid JavaScript code. So the remaining question is: is it possible or not?

Answer (score 4):

The question is old of cource but it will be helpful to others so giving the answer.

Yes it is possible to get them both. Below is the example from the PrimeFaces demo for the editable combobox.

```
<p:outputLabel for="city" value="Editable: " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{selectOneMenuView.city}" effect="fold" editable="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.cities}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

You can add another attribute to this one and get the characteristics of advanced also together with the editable.

```
<p:outputLabel for="city" value="Editable: " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{selectOneMenuView.city}" effect="fold" editable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.cities}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And you are done. You got both.